# Chart.js Radar chart legend label font size doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I am using Chart.js.

I want to make my chart legend label font size more bigger.

So I tried like this:

```
var ctx = $('#skill_chart');

new Chart(ctx,{
    "type":"radar",
    "data": {
            "labels":["Crawling","Django","Ubuntu Server","Coding","Cycling","Running"],
            "datasets":[{
                    "label":"My Second Dataset",
                    "data":[28,48,40,19,96,27,100],
                    "fill":true,
                    "backgroundColor":"rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
                    "borderColor":"rgb(54, 162, 235)",
                    "pointBackgroundColor":"rgb(54, 162, 235)",
                    "pointBorderColor":"#fff",
                    "pointHoverBackgroundColor":"#fff",
                    "pointHoverBorderColor":"rgb(54, 162, 235)"}]
                },
    "options":{
        "elements":{
        "line":{
            "tension":0,
            "borderWidth":3}
            }
        },

        "legend": {
            "display": true,
            "labels": {
                "fontSize": 20,
            }
        },
    });
```

But It doesn't work.
What should I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `legend` object is outside the `options` object. It needs to be within the `options` object. The following code will work:

```
var ctx = $('#skill_chart');

new Chart(ctx,{
    "type":"radar",
    "data": {
            "labels":["Crawling","Django","Ubuntu Server","Coding","Cycling","Running"],
            "datasets":[{
                    "label":"My Second Dataset",
                    "data":[28,48,40,19,96,27,100],
                    "fill":true,
                    "backgroundColor":"rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
                    "borderColor":"rgb(54, 162, 235)",
                    "pointBackgroundColor":"rgb(54, 162, 235)",
                    "pointBorderColor":"#fff",
                    "pointHoverBackgroundColor":"#fff",
                    "pointHoverBorderColor":"rgb(54, 162, 235)"}]
                },
    "options":{
        "elements":{
            "line":{
                "tension":0,
                "borderWidth":3
            }
        },

        "legend": {
            "display": true,
            "labels": {
                "fontSize": 20,
            }
        },
    }
});
```

Here is a link to the docs for fonts: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/fonts.html

Comment: OMG then How can I increase font size ["Crawling","Django","Ubuntu Server","Coding","Cycling","Running"] in the chart?

Comment: @황준필 If the answer helped you then can you please accept it?

Answer (score 3):

You have to set `fontSize` inside `pointLables` object in `scale` object at your configuration. The following options works to customize the font size of labels in data (as you asked in response to @Rounak )

```
radarOptions: {
    scale: {
        pointLabels: {
            fontSize: 13
        }
    }
}
```

All credits to: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2854#issuecomment-331057910